# R grep() and gsub() : remove the matched strings and also include the unmatched strings and store all the observations in a character vector

Tags: r, regex

I have a data-frame `transactions`

```
Cust_no  date      debit  credit  comment
1234    12DEC2013      0     100  ATMW XYZ 8974632
1234    11DEC2013    200       0  TFR - XXXX3948389
1543    01DEC2013   3000       0  SAL - CitiBank
1543    02DEC2013      0     800  CHQ TO FAMILY
1543    10DEC2014     10       0  INSURANCE GENERALE
7777    01DEC2014   2500       0  SALARY/01-12-2013/ENJOY
```

My goal is to remove all the banking terms , special characters and other unwanted things from `comment` column, store it in a variable and add as new column to the same table. So, I used `grep()` with `gsub()`

```
listOfTerms <- ... #the regular expression that contains terms to be removed

NewComment <- gsub(paste(listOfTerms,collapse="|"), " ", transactions[grep(paste(listOfTerms,collapse="|") ,transactions$comment,ignore.case=TRUE),])
```

But the problem is `NewComment` has elements for matched patterns only, and that it gives me a `Large Character` instead of a `vector`

I have tried using `sub()` but even then, obviously, I'm getting the same output.

So, how do I tell `gsub(pattern,grep(...))` to not to do anything if it encounters an unmatched string and add the "corrected" rows and unmatched rows in one **vector**? Required output is shown below.

```
Cust_no  date      debit  credit  comment                  NewComment
1234    12DEC2013      0     100  ATMW XYZ 8974632         XYZ
1234    11DEC2013    200       0  TFR - XXXX3948389        XXXX
1543    01DEC2013   3000       0  SAL - CitiBank           CitiBank
1543    02DEC2013      0     800  CHQ TO FAMILY            TO FAMILY
1543    10DEC2014     10       0  INSURANCE GENERALE       INSURANCE GENERALE
7777    01DEC2014   2500       0  SALARY/01-12-2013/ENJOY  ENJOY
```

Comment: Well without `grep` how should I match patterns using `gsub` alone? Is there any method, maybe I'm unaware of?

Comment: Can you provide the pattern you are trying to match?

Comment: You could use `regmatches` with `invert = TRUE` to return the non-matching characters

Comment: @DavidArenburg here it goes.. atleast some of them, just for example sake and to match the sample data frame in the question

`listOfTerms <- c("ATM","ATMW","CHQ","SAL","SALARY","BY")` and so on..

Comment: @RichardScriven thing is, I want both matched and unmatched. Matched should have the matching pattern removed and unmatched should be left as it is.

Comment: @NicE Holy ... !! But how?? Its actually working mate..!!! I thought `grep()` was mandatory and was totally ignorant and adamant about using `gsub` alone. Please write it as answer, you deserve a lot of reps..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `gsub` without the `grep`, `gsub` will replace the parts of each strings that match the pattern, and if there is no match, you will get the original string.

Try:

```
transactions$NewComment<-gsub(paste(listOfTerms,collapse="|"),"",transactions$comment)
```